# how to declare multiple kwargs in python 3.4?

Tags: python, django

hi guys I mention like this in Django views.py
In my machine python 3.8 and Django 3.0.8 is running

```
serializer = {**nameserializer,**nameserializer,**nameserializer}
```

deployment machine is running in python 3.4 and django 2.0

so please help me to solve this error

```
serializer = {**nameserializer,**nameserializer,**nameserializer}
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

help me to fix this..

Comment: If `nameserializer` is a dictionary, then dictionary unpacking (e.g. `{**a, **b}`) is available from Python 3.5 only.

Answer (score 3):

If `nameserializer` is a dictionary, then dictionary unpacking (e.g. `{**a, **b}`) is available only starting from Python 3.5. That explains why it works for you in Python 3.8 and not in Python 3.4.

**PEP-0448:** https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/.

Comment: Thanks, but How to fix that in 3.4 or how to use different methods for this to get the same output..

Comment: @Gowthamns There is a dictionary method called [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) which could help you. On the side note, I would highly recommend you to upgrade your deployment machine, as Python 3.4 is not maintained anymore.